# Does there exist a telnet-like  for SSL connections?

Tags: ssl, https, telnet

are there any telnet-like tool that can manually debug a `https` connection byte by byte?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: found it:

`$ openssl s_client -connect pop.gmail.com:995`